# Selenium click method is executing and then timing out

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait

I am using the selenium webdriver to run my automation tests. One of my tests opens a login page, enters credentials and clicks the login button. When I run it locally I can see that it has successfully logged in to the site but then my test throws an error on the click method even though I've seen it move onto the next page. I'm also using Chrome Driver.

The text on the error says:

> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'The HTTP request to the remote
>   WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:4444/click timed out after
>   60 seconds.
>
> Inner Exception WebException: The request was aborted: The operation
>   has timed out.

This is the code I'm using to locate the element and to click it:

```
private IWebElement LoginButton => Wait.Until(d => Driver.FindElementByCssSelector(".btn"));

private void ClickLoginButton()
{                               
    LoginButton.Click();
}
```

Other click methods for other sites are working fine, I only seem to be seeing this error with this button.

Comment: What are your `chromedriver` and browser versions?

Comment: @guy Chrome browser version is 68.0.3440.106 and chromedriver is 2.41

Comment: The browser has navigated to the next page but if you look carefully, the page is still loading in the browser. There are many, many potential reasons for this... slow internet, problems with the page or web server, and so on. Does it consistently happen? Does it happen when you execute the scenario manually? Do you have access to the devs? If so, ask them why it might be happening and maybe they can investigate and find a fix.

Answer (score 2):

When Selenium executes `click()` it will try to wait for the page to load. From the [docs](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebElement_Click.htm)

> the Click() method will attempt to block until the page has loaded

If the `IWebDriver` doesn't receive this indication (`document.readyState` if memory serves) it will end with the `WebDriverException`.

There isn't any "pretty" solution. One option is to set `ChromeOption` in the driver initialization

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("pageLoadStrategy","none");
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

But this will effect **all the tests**.

Another option is to catch `WebDriverTimeoutException` in this particular button

```
private void ClickLoginButton()
{
    try
    {
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetPageLoadTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));    
        LoginButton.Click();
    }
    catch (WebDriverTimeoutException) { }
    finally
    {
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetPageLoadTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(originalTime));
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to have the page load timeout set to 1s? It seems like you would set it higher than 60s for this case.

Comment: @JeffC The click navigates to the next page, the OP can see it. If it isn't loafed in 60 seconds it probably won't be loaded with longer time, so there is no point waiting for 60 seconds either.

Comment: Yeah but 1s? That's pretty much guaranteed to fail on even a well engineered site/page. Either way, that doesn't really solve the problem. It just fails faster... and likely will be false negatives in many cases.

Comment: @JeffC I metioned this solution is for this button where we know there is a problem.

Comment: This button is the login button. I'm assuming it's going to be used a LOT. Causing it to instantly (1s) fail is not really a solution to the problem, is it?

Comment: @JeffC The problem exists wheather the button is cliked one time or 1000 times. IMO this is the best solution from the alternatives.

Comment: @Guy I changed the Selenium Standalone Server from 3.13.0 to 3.11.0 and the test was able to carry on. Although I then hit that error again on another click method later on in my test. The test implements multiple click methods before the one it errors on.

Answer (score 0):

My case was solved when I waited until element to be clickable:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(element)).Click();
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue:
The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:17553/session/1a94ba744cb6dc03af7d65bf58003eff/element/0.42183143444524296-3/click **timed out after 60 second**

specifying timeout in ChromeDriver constructor helped in my scenario

```
            /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ChromeDriver"/> class using the specified path
    /// to the directory containing ChromeDriver.exe, options, and command timeout.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="chromeDriverDirectory">The full path to the directory containing ChromeDriver.exe.</param>
    /// <param name="options">The <see cref="ChromeOptions"/> to be used with the Chrome driver.</param>
    /// <param name="commandTimeout">The maximum amount of time to wait for each command.</param>
    public ChromeDriver(string chromeDriverDirectory, ChromeOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
        : this(ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(chromeDriverDirectory), options, commandTimeout)
    {
    }
```